# Validation With Child Record Query

Tags: validation

I want to force users to populate some fields on the Opportunity object when Opportunity fields meet criteria and certain products are used in the Opportunity Product.

Is there a way to force a validation when the Opportunity is edited to check the related records?

I want to avoid rollups because the solution may have to scale to multiple business units, and we can only have so many rollup summary fields per object.

Comment: you need to use trigger/apex code for this

Comment: I've never built a validation in code, at a high level though it's a list query for the Opportunitylineitem records and then an if statement with list.slize() != 0 && field == x && field == y?

Comment: yes, you can post whatever you are tried so far.

Comment: I haven't yet, I wasn't sure if it was possible so I didn't want to spend hours banging my head on something to find out it couldn't be done that way.

Comment: You can reference parent record fields in validation rule from Child record..but vice versa (refer child record from parent record ) is not possible.For that you need to write trigger/apex as suggested by Santanu